# JSON.parse: unexpected character - what character am I missing?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Environment: PHP 5.3.5 MySQL Server 5.5.8, jquery version 1.6

Using Ajax to auto-populate a dropdown list of countries.

I keep getting this error and I have tried numerous things. Such as surround the $results with "'$results'" before encoding. The error still persists.

Here is the an example of output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "45"
    [0]=>
    string(2) "45"
    ["nicename"]=>
    string(16) "Christmas Island"
    [1]=>
    string(16) "Christmas Island"
  }
}
```

Here is the ajax (I even tried to change success to complete - the error code is just duplicated if I do that.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "models/ajaxHandler.php",
    data: {handler:"getCountries", nli:"-1"}, 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(results){
        //results = $.parseJSON(results);
        var resultStr = "";

        for(var x in results)
            resultStr = resultStr + results[x]; 
        alert("RESULT" + resultStr);


        //populateDropDown(results);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
        alert(xhr+ "| ajax failure: could not populate list of countires | " + status + " | error:" + error);
        var xhrStr = "";
        for(var x in xhr)
            xhrStr = xhrStr + xhr[x];
        alert(xhrStr);
    }
});
```

After I encode the json string in php I am escaping for special characters like so:

```
if (!empty($results)){
        $json = json_encode($results);
        //$json = form_safe_json($json);
        echo $json;
}

function form_safe_json($json) {
            $json = empty($json) ? '[]' : $json ;
            $search = array('\\',"\n","\r","\f","\t","\b","'") ;
            $replace = array('\\\\',"\\n", "\\r","\\f","\\t","\\b", "\'");
            $json = str_replace($search,$replace,$json);
            return $json;
}
```

Comment: It's not that you're missing the character, it's that there is an extra character or a character that isn't supposed to be there. Look at exactly what your server is returning. I don't see any echo statements in your php, so i'd expect it to be returning nothing.

Comment: Try to remove the call to `form_safe_json` (this isn't needed) and loose the double quotes around `$results`.

Comment: you might be able to use [this online JSON parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) to check where the error lies...

Comment: `alert("RESULT".resultStr);` php concatenation doesn't work in javascript, you'll want a `+` there rather than `.`

Comment: I suggest removing your `form_safe_json` function.  `json_encode` will form "safe" JSON for you.

Comment: i removed the form_safe_json, I removed the quotes around $results, corrected the alert statement and echo the response as above. still getting the same issue.

Comment: What does `console.log(results);` show you?

Comment: an example of the echo statement is now this  [{"id":"45","0":"45","nicename":"Christmas Island","1":"Christmas Island"}]

Comment: @user2672744: That's valid JSON.

Comment: In your PHP, you shouldn't need to check for results being empty, `json_encode` would write it as an empty array which is better than outputting nothing, which might cause an error. In your javascript, you should be getting your values out of the results like `results[x].id` and `results[x].nicename`. You shouldn't use parseJSON, the ajax success function will automatically parse it into an object for you since you've specified json as your dataType

Comment: @KevinB I am still so new to this, if you couldn't already tell. I am learning and your mention of not using echo and extra characters now makes sense. I had an extra echo statement there for debugging and that was being concatenated to the result so when it returned to the success it failed. I gotta be more careful! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

> After I encode the json string in php I am escaping for special characters

You don't need to do that -- `json_encode()` does all the necessary escaping for you, and in fact doing so is probably breaking the valid JSON that `json_encode()` has produced for you.

[EDIT]

To be clear: PHP's `json_encode()` function produces valid JSON from any input. (The only thing you need to test for is `false` if it fails, but even that will parse correctly in jQuery if you echo it, since an empty string is valid JSON).

If your program echos the output of `json_encode()`, and nothing else, then your program will be serving valid JSON and will not get the JSON parsing error in your JS code.

If your program echos anything else, or if you modify the JSON string before sending it, you may very well get errors.

Things to watch out for:

- Don't try to send multiple JSON strings one after the other using multiple calls to `json_encode()`. This will be invalid JSON. Encode everything you want to send using a single call to `json_encode()`.
- Beware of PHP sending unwanted characters (particularly white space and UTF-8 BOM characters) which can cause errors in many situations.
- If errors persist, load your JSON URL into the browser direct and view the source. You may see the error straight away. If not, copy and paste the JSON string into [one of the JSON test sites on the web](http://jsonlint.com/) and see what it reports. This may help explain the problem.
- If you're on PHP 5.4, you can use the `PRETTY_PRINT` option in `json_encode()`. This may help you with your debugging.

Comment: i removed the escaping but the issue still occurs.

Comment: btw I added this function because I was getting that error. I removed it only to still get that error.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into upgrading my PHP this weekend and consider this pretty print!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `json_encode()` could be of some use? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Your function is essentially trying to do what `json_encode` already does. I'd recommend scrapping your function and using `json_encode` instead.

Comment: I added this function because I was getting that error. I removed it only to still get that error.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you try to achieve with the `form_safe_json` command.

The text string returned from:

```
$json = json_encode($result);
```

will contain correctly formated json and should not be further escaped in case you wish for the Javascript to parse it correctly. The escaping made by `form_safe_json` will break the json.

Comment: I added this function because I was getting that error. I removed it only to still get that error.